# MySQL Group By and Order By used together

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is a really strange one, I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now. I have searched high and low for an answer on this one, and I just simply can't find one. I am a but stuck, and would really appreciate it if someone could assist me here.

First and foremost, I have created an SQL Fiddle for this. It is simply so hard for me to explain this, and I felt that was the best way for people to get an idea of my schema and data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5da89/3

So, here is what I am trying to do:

- Select rows from `wp_bbpas` that are no older than 24 hours
- Join the data I have onto the `wp_users` table, so I can get usernames and such
- Return the data

What's actually happening, is it's selecting the maximum `date_recorded` for each row (which is what I want, as there can be hundreds of these returned per query), it then returns what seems to be the correct data - however, upon closer inspection (using the index keys) you will see it is infact mixing up the contents completely. (`id` 334 has a different `date_recorded` to that of which was returned)

Am I misusing the `GROUP BY` functionality here? Can anyone point out exactly what I have done wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You are misusing the `GROUP BY` functionality.  You have columns in the `SELECT` that are not arguments to aggregation functions and are not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a subselect like this

```
SELECT p.date_recorded as date_recorded, p.id, p.userid, p.status, w.user_nicename, w.user_login, w.display_name
FROM wp_bbpas AS p
JOIN wp_users AS w ON w.id = p.userid
WHERE date_recorded >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
and (p.userid, p.date_recorded) in (  select  userid, MAX(date_recorded)
                         from wp_bbpas  group by userid)
ORDER BY date_recorded DESC
```

Comment: This works perfectly it seems, now my concern lies with performance. See, I did have this as a solution however this query would take far too long with larger sets of data (took around 2 seconds for about 20 rows)

Comment: have you proper index where needed? ... 20 rows for result ...but how many rows for wp_users and wp_bbpas?

Comment: `wp_users` has around 140 rows, `wp_bbpas` has around 350. That can grow exponentially, however, the where statement should cut that down drastically.

Since I am working with the WordPress schema for `wp_users`, I am unable to control indexes there... however, everything looks fine and in `wp_bbpas` I have id, userid and date_recorded indexed

Comment: If you need this kind of select ( id with aggregate function) tthe technique is this ( or inner join  ..but more complex to lead at the expected result)  ..Anyway  is better a functioning select a bit slow that a fast wrong result  .. i think ..

Comment: that's a good point, and I understand, however - this is a free plugin I have developed for WordPress and I'm the sort of stubborn person who just won't let an update go out unless it's performance is top-notch. I will try to have a play around with it and see where it gets me, I am considering to pull all the data and then manipulate in PHP (since this would be much quicker)

Comment: Well you asked for a question and i think to provide you a correct answer .. ..and i think you performance issue is strange to few rows involved for so bad performance .. check for some problem not properly related to this query..

Comment: You can increase the speed by adding the same contition to your subselect: `WHERE date_recorded >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR`

Comment: Scais, don't worry I will be marking your answer as the solution - I will probably play with the query a little to see if there are any further tweaks to be made. Thanks Paul, that has helped a little in this case!

Answer (score 1):

This one returns what you're expecting, isn't it?

```
SELECT p.date_recorded, p.id, p.userid, p.status, w.user_nicename, w.user_login, w.display_name
FROM wp_bbpas AS p
JOIN wp_users AS w ON w.id = p.userid
WHERE date_recorded >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
GROUP BY p.userId
ORDER BY date_recorded DESC
```

(You don't need the `max(date_recorded)` as the data is ordered by this filed)

Comment: Only problem with this solution is it is not returning the most recent rows